# How to communicate via socket with two computers in local network

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

I want to send data from a computer to another using sockets (Server/Client), I searched for a solution but I didn't found any one helpful, can anyone help me please.

here is my Server code :

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
class server
{
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
    try
       {

        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(3006);
        Socket s = server.accept();
        System.out.println("connected!");   

        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        dos.writeUTF("Welcom to socket");
       }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();     
       }
    }   
}
```

And this is my Client code: (192.168.1.5 is the Server's locale address)

```
 import java.net.*;
 import java.io.*;
 class client 
 {
    static InetAddress LocaleAdresse;
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
       try
        {
        System.out.println("client execute");
        Socket s = new Socket("192.168.1.5", 3006);

        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream (s.getInputStream());
        String msg = dis.readUTF();
        System.out.println(msg);
        s.close();          
        }
            catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: your code works for me; server should flush() and close() the output stream, but even without those, it works fine. Try using "0.0.0.0" as your IP address, and also make sure you run Server first and then the client.

Comment: thank you @diginoise for your comment, for me the code works only locally (in one computer), but it doesn't work for external connection (two computers). Did you tried to run it from tow different computers connected in LAN?

Comment: I tested running only locally unfortunately. Try printing what address is `ServerSocket` bound to after the constructor, or check if `server.isBound() == true` if bound and you have the address (it's probably going to be 0.0.0.0 verify whether you can telnet to that IP address and socket. So for me calling `telnet 127.0.0.1 3006` on Win produced the desired output of `Welcome to socket` and then connection close.

Comment: Check your firewall.